# Process a block of HTML, ignoring content within specific tags

Tags: php, regex

On a blog I wish to pass all of the text for a blog entry through a PHP script to process quotes and some other items into nice typographic characters.

The blog text in question contains HTML, and in particular will highlight code snippets contained within `<pre><code> ... </code></pre>` blocks. The `code` blocks can appear randomly and in multiple places within the text (much like Stack Overflow!)

**I do not want those code blocks processed by the typographic scripts I will be using.** *The processing itself is not the point, being able to selectively apply it is.*

I have been able to write a regex to find those blocks:

```
preg_match_all('/(<pre><code>(.*?)<\/code><\/pre>)/s', $text, $matches);
```

But I am not sure what the best way is to process the rest of the text and then slot these blocks back into their correct places.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first solution that comes to my mind looks like this :

- extract all the codes
- remove the codes, replacing them with a special marker, that will not be affected by your string manipulations -- that marker has to be really special (and you could verify it's not present in the input string, btw)
- do your manipulations on the string
- put back the codes, where there are markers now

In code, it could be something like this :
*(sorry, it's quite long -- and I didn't include any check ; it's up to you to add those)*

```
$str = <<<A
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sodales lacus et erat accumsan consectetur. Sed lacinia enim vitae erat suscipit fermentum. Quisque lobortis nisi et lacus imperdiet ac malesuada dui imperdiet. <pre><code>ThIs Is 
CoDe 1</code></pre>Donec vestibulum commodo quam rhoncus luctus. Nam vitae ipsum sed nibh dignissim condimentum. Sed ultrices fermentum dapibus. Vivamus mattis nisi nec enim convallis quis aliquet arcu accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Nullam eget fringilla nunc. Nulla porta justo justo. Nunc consectetur egestas malesuada. Mauris ac nisi ipsum, et accumsan lorem. Quisque interdum accumsan pellentesque. Sed at felis metus. Nulla gravida tincidunt tortor, <pre><code>AnD cOdE 2</code></pre>nec aliquam tortor ultricies vel. Integer semper libero eu magna congue eget lacinia purus auctor. Nunc volutpat ultricies feugiat. Nullam id mauris eget ipsum ultricies ullamcorper non vel risus. Proin volutpat volutpat interdum. Nulla orci odio, ornare sit amet ullamcorper non, condimentum sagittis libero. <pre><code>aNd
CoDe
NuMbEr 3
</code></pre>Ut non justo at neque convallis luctus ultricies amet. 
A;
var_dump($str);

// Extract the codes
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('#<pre><code>(.*?)</code></pre>#s', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);

// Remove the codes
$str_nocode = preg_replace('#<pre><code>.*?</code></pre>#s', 'THIS_IS_A_NOCODE_MARKER', $str);
var_dump($str_nocode);

// Do whaterver you want with $str_nocode
$str_nocode = strtoupper($str_nocode);
var_dump($str_nocode);

// And put back the codes :
$str_codes = $str_nocode;
foreach ($matches[0] as $code) {
    $str_codes = preg_replace('#THIS_IS_A_NOCODE_MARKER#', $code, $str_codes, 1);
}
var_dump($str_codes);
```

I've tried with :

- code on one line,
- code on 2 lines,
- and code on multiple lines

Note : you should really test more than I did -- but this could give you a first idea...

Hope this helps :-)

As a side note : generally, parsing HTML with regexes is considered bad practice, and often leads to troubles... Maybe using something like [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) could be an idea worth having a look ?

Comment: Ahh I think I get it. As far as DOMDocument goes: so you're thinking it's better to use something like DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName to pull the <pre> block than using preg_match?

Comment: Didn't say it *is*, but it *might*, in some case (yeah, I'm kinda overly careful :-D ) ^^ I don't know much of your application, and if you really know what kinda stuff comes in, a couple a regex would be just fine (In you situation, I would probably use those ; and only search for another solution if regex don't work after some tunning). But, in a (more ? ) complex case, regex are often not the best tool for HTML "parsing". About getElementsByTagName, maybe -- I'd probably first try something with Xpath, though, at least for fun ^^

Comment: Thanks Pascal, this works well. I'm using microtime() to salt the token so its always unique and shouldn't collide with any user text. I really like rojoca's solution below, but I am going to use this one as I only have to process the text once, instead of multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting everything you need back from `preg_match_all()` then you could leverage `preg_split()` like so:

```
$pattern = '/(<pre><code>(.*?)<\/code><\/pre>)/s';

// get the code blocks
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
$code_blocks = $matches[0];

// split up the text around the code blocks into an array
$unprocessed = preg_split($pattern, $text);
$processed_text = '';
foreach($unprocessed as $block) {

    // process the text here
    $processed_text .= process($block); 

    // add the next code block
    if(!empty($code_blocks)) $processed_text .= array_shift($code_blocks);
}

// any remaining
$processed_text .= implode('', $code_blocks);
```

This has the unfortunate drawback of having to do multiple `process()` calls so depending on how intensive that is and how often you do it this may not be the best solution. It is pretty clear and safe though and you don't have to add any special markers for replacement later.

If your processing is doing white listing and safety type stuff then have a look at [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org) which can do some sophisticated filtering of HTML that may let you avoid this type of stuff altogether (don't quote me on that though).

Comment: This is nice, and your solution follows along the same thought processes I was having to solve the problem. I am going with Pascal's answer because I only have to process the text once, but I will probably be using a variant of your solution in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Textile](http://textile.thresholdstate.com/) which allows for markdown-like text formatting and HTML. It's super easy to use and I think it should solve the problem if I understand it right.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to convert quotes, or a small list of items, I would just use string_replace.

$text = <<

```
Some code here
```

HEREDOC;

$search_and_replace = array('"', '"', "'", ''');
$newtest = str_replace( array_keys( $search_and_replace ), $search_and_replace, $text);

Unless you are looking for something like strip_tags, which allows you to specify which HTML tags you want to keep.

Comment: I'm doing a lot more than converting quotes and I am not stripping tags. The point is it shouldn't matter what processing I'm doing, I don't want it to happen to specific chunks within the text.

Comment: You're missing the point. I know how markdown works. I'm asking how to selectively process only certain parts of a text while ignoring others.

Comment: I don't think Gumbo was talking to you, darren_n (though that was my first impression, too). I believe he was advising Brent to learn how to use the formatting tools here on SO--advice which I heartily endorse.