# WMD Markdown and server-side

Tags: php, markdown, wmd

I have worked the last 2 days on [WMD](http://code.google.com/p/wmd/) and [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), and I don't find THE solution for stock data with security. I would like users to be able to post HTML/XML <code> (with WMD) on my site.

For the moment, I stock data in the Markdown format, but if I disable JavaScript the user can easily push XSS. If I `strip_tags` or `html_entities` all data I lose the user HTML/XML <code>. How can I do it?

In my opinion I must `html_entities` just the code between pre /pre, but how?! My data is in Markdown.

After, what can I do to forbid XSS attributes:

```
<img src="javascript:alert('xss');" />
```

Answer (score 2):

To "clean" your HTML, you could use a tool like [`HTML Purifier`](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Basically, it allows you to specify which tags/attributes are allowed, an only keeps those.

It also produces valid (X)HTML code as ouput -- which is nice.

You can see on the [demo page](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php) there is an example that is almost exactly the XSS you posted, btw ;-)

For instance, you can try with some HTML like this one :

```
test <img src="javascript:evil();" onload="evil();" /> 
test <img src="http://www.google.com/a.Png" /> test2
```

The output is :

```
test  test <img src="http://www.google.com/a.Png" alt="a.Png" /> test2
```

The `img` tag with XSS has not been kept ; the other one has ; and there's been an `alt` attribute added, to be standard-compliant.

It might not solve all your problems, but if you are giving users the possiblity to input HTML, is it definitly useful *(would I dare saying "it's a must-have" ? )*

Comment: thanks for u reply. I known html purifier and other "sanitizer". The real probleme is : how can I do for not loose the html basic layout (by wmd) and the html inserted by user in <code>..</code>

Comment: Basic layout > if it's just some simple tags, you can define those as "allowed" for HTMLPurifier, so they are not removed. If you want to allow HTML inserted between special tags, take a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155443/process-a-block-of-html-ignoring-content-within-specific-tags/1155530#1155530 ; by mixing that and HTMLPurifier, you might get to what you want ?